# How do you match one of two words in a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match either @ or 'at' in a regex. Can someone help? I tried using the ? operator, giving me /@?(at)?/ but that didn't work

Comment: [Regular expression containing one word or another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17166618/995714)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try:

```
/(@|at)/
```

This means either `@` or `at` but not both. It's also captured in a group, so you can later access the exact match through a backreference if you want to.

Comment: would this handle cases where the email address is something like atproperties@something.com, or latitudeataddress.com?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: would it produce false positive matches is what I'm asking I guess.

Comment: Of course it would produce false positives! Regular expressions can't read your mind.

Comment: right... so then would the OP be better served with a regex that attempts to reduce that possiblity in your opinion? I think that you could improve upon it, but at the cost of increased complexity. Would that be worth it though?

Answer (score 43):

```
/(?:@|at)/
```

mmyers' answer will perform a paren capture; mine won't.  Which you should use depends on whether you want the paren capture.

Comment: Is it some kind of lookaround? I haven't found "?:". Damn google.

Comment: @Qwerty: `(?:)` is grouping without capture, as opposed to `()` that captures.

Answer (score 4):

if that's only 2 things you want to capture, no need regex

```
if ( strpos($string,"@")!==FALSE || strpos($string,"at") !==FALSE ) {
  # do your thing
}
```

Comment: True. I was assuming this was part of something bigger, but if not, this is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried

```
@|at
```

that works for (in the .NET regex flavor) the following text

johnsmith@gmail.com
johnsmithatgmail.com

Comment: This will also match `jonsmith@atgmail.com`   Is there a way to match either one but not both in a row? My use case is routing for someone with a nickname. I need to match `www.domain.com/name` and `www.domain.com/nickname` but not `www.domain.com/namenickname`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
^(\w*(@|at))
```

For:

- **johnsmith@** gmail.com
- **johnsmithat**gmail.com
- **jonsmith@** atgmail.com