# Regular expression containing one word or another

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to create an expression matching a whole number followed by either "seconds" or "minutes"

I tried this expression: `([0-9]+)\s+(\bseconds\b)|(\bminutes\b)`

It works fine for seconds, but not minutes.

E.g. "5 seconds" gives 5;seconds;
while "5 minutes" gives ;;minutes

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You just missed an extra pair of brackets for the "OR" symbol. The following should do the trick:

```
([0-9]+)\s+((\bseconds\b)|(\bminutes\b))
```

Without those you were either matching a number followed by seconds OR just the word minutes

Comment: but thats an "extra match" that is not required. Either use `([0-9]+)\s+(?:(\bseconds\b)|(\bminutes\b))` or `([0-9]+)\s+(\bseconds\b|\bminutes\b)`

Comment: Yea that's true, no need for the brackets around \bseconds\b and \bminutes\b!

Answer (score 64):

You can use a single group for seconds/minutes. The following expression may suit your needs:

```
([0-9]+)\s*(seconds|minutes)
```

### [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQ0Qit/2)

Answer (score 5):

If you care about the word boundaries and want to keep matches to a minimum use this:

```
([0-9]+)\s*\b(seconds|minutes)\b
```

Comment: This will not work if there is no spaces between number and text.

Comment: @Toto the original question has a space between the number and the word. If you want to make that space optional, then leave out the first '\b'.