# Cypress expect element to contain one string or another string

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to do some Cypress assertions to see whether or not it contains one or another string. It can be in English or Spanish, so either one should pass the test.

```
cy.get(el).should('contain', 'submit').or('contain', 'enviar')
```

obviously doesnt work.

```
  const runout = ['submit', 'enviar']
  const el = '[data-test=btn-submit]'
  function checkArray(arr, el) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(cy.get(el).contains(arr[i])) {
        return true
      } else {
        if (i === arr.length) {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cy.expect(checkArray(runout,el)).to.be.true
```

fails the test, still checking both strings.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try a regular expression, see [contains#Regular-Expression](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Regular-Expression).

See this question [Regular expression containing one word or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166618/regular-expression-containing-one-word-or-another) for some formats

I think something as simple as this will do it,

```js
cy.get(el).contains(/submit|enviar/g)
```

Experiment first on [Regex101](https://regex101.com) or similar online tester.

Maybe build it with

```js
const runout = ['submit', 'enviar']
const regex = new RegExp(`${runout.join('|')}`, 'g')
cy.get(el).contains(regex)
```

Comment: How does this work with numbers?

Comment: Elements only contain strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way is able to check 'Or' condtion. 
I used google homepage to test and try to find either 'Google Search' or 'Not Google Search' in my test.
If cannot find both will throw an error.

```
describe('check if contains one of the text', function() 
{
it('Test google search button on google homepage',()=> {
    let url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    let word1 = 'Not Google Search';
    let word2 = 'Google Search';
    cy.visit(url);
    cy.get('input[value="Google Search"]').invoke('attr','value').then((text)=>{

        if (text=== word1) {
            console.log('found google not search');
        }
        else if (text === word2) {
            console.log('found google search');
        }
        else {
            console.log(text);
            throw ("cannot find any of them");
        }

    })
})
})
```

In the test case above word2 is found so it logged 'Found google search' in the console.

[image]

Comment: This does work but only to a certain extent. Sometimes the .get yields too much text and i can't specify any less, which is why contains is needed.

Comment: what about replacing the if (text === word1) to if (text.includes(word1))? And furthermore you can write your own commands with this function and take word1, word2 as parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a typesafe command to `cy`, this might be helpful:

```
declare global {
   namespace Cypress {
      interface Chainable {
         contains1of(selector: string, these: string[]): Chainable
      }
   }
}

Cypress.Commands.add("contains1of", (selector, these) => {
   let css = these.map((s) => selector + ":contains('" + s + "')").join(",")
   return cy.get(css).first()
})
```

Given your selector `const el = '[data-test=btn-submit]'`,
the usage is:

`cy.contains1of(el, ['submit', 'enviar'])`

which is aimed to look and work similar to the existing command `cy.contains(el, 'submit')`.