# Can we test if element text includes text_ A or text_B with cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

Just wondering if there is a way to test that an element contains **text_A** or **text_B** with cypress. For example, I have an element that is filled with the error returned from an API request and I want to check whether the error message includes **text_A** or **text_B**. Tried the following code but it works only if **text_A** is present and fails when **text_B** is returned.I don't get any error for invalid syntax from cypress, any help would be appreciated.

```
 cy.get('body').then((body) => { 
     if (body.find('#request-error').length > 0) { 
         cy.get('#request-error').then((el)=> {
              assert.include(el.text(), ('text_A' || 'text_B')); 
         });
     } else {
         // DO SOMETHING ELSE
     }
 });
```

Comment: Try `cy.get('#request-error').contains(/text_A|text_B/g)`, from this question [Cypress expect element to contain one string or another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176344/cypress-expect-element-to-contain-one-string-or-another-string)

Comment: Hi @Ackroydd thanks for the answer. I managed to make it work using the idea described to the link you provided. 
```const runout = ['text_A', 'text_B']    
const regex = new RegExp(`${runout.join('|')}`)    
const text = el.text()    
expect(text).to.match(regex)    
```

Comment: Just one additional thing, you're doing this within the `.then((el) => ...`. Did you try out `.contains(regex)`? I notice from your comment to Cory that there's a substring factor and was wondering if that scenario also works with the simpler `.contains(regex)`.

Answer (score 8):

Essentially you have an array of possible error messages, so you can test if the element's text exists within that array.

```js
expect(['text_A', 'text_B']).to.include(el.text())
```

Another option that reads better would be to use `.oneOf`

```js
expect(el.text()).to.be.oneOf(['text_A', 'text_B']);
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions

Comment: Hi Cory, thank you for the answer. However I don't think that this solution can be applied to my case since I want the opposite; text_A or text_B should be included to el.text(). For example el.text() = 'foo text_A bar' or el.text() = 'foo text_B bar'. Tried to  switch the arguments and wrote: expect(el.text()).to.include([text_A', 'text_B']) but it failed with error AssertionError: expected 'foo text_A bar' to include [ 'text_A', 'text_B' ]

Comment: Ahhh I see. Glad to see that you were able to get help with your issue in the comments!

Answer (score 3):

I am late but you can do it with satisfy:

```
 cy.get('.text-element').invoke('text').then(text => {
      expect(text).to.satisfy((mText: string) => possibleMatchesArray.includes(mText));
 });
```

Comment: Cypress in Firefox says: “possibleMatchesArray is not defined”